# How do I update data on Kendo-UI grid and persist hierarchy selection using Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I have an Angular single page app with a kendo grid that is bound to a RESTful API. When this data is updated externally, I have a web socket (PubNub) function I am triggering with the intent to refresh and display externally changed data while preserving the hierarchy of the grid as well as selected row.

I can get the data grid to refresh but this doesn't refresh the datasource with the changed data from the API.   If I include a dataSource.read(), then it seems to prevent my persistence of the hierarchy, IE it closes previously opened hierarchical grids.

I have an tried to use the example from the Telerik Docs for this listed here: [Persist expanded rows after refresh](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/how-to/persist-expanded-rows)

```
vm.savestate = function(e) {

        console.log('save pressed:');
        var grid = $scope.responseGrid;
        var expanded = $.map(grid.tbody.children(":has(> .k-hierarchy-cell .k-minus)"), function(row) {

            console.log(row);
            console.log($(row).data("uid"));
            return $(row).data("uid");

        });

        grid.one("dataBound", function() {
            grid.expandRow(grid.tbody.children().filter(function(idx, row) {
                return $.inArray($(row).data("uid"), expanded) >= 0;
            }));
        });

         grid.refresh();


    };
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution was rather simple actually.   You can't use the uid as this is generated upon each new read for the observable array.  The correct choice is to use a model id as the below example:

```
vm.savestate = function(e) {

    console.log('save pressed:');
    var grid = $scope.responseGrid;
    var expanded = $.map(grid.tbody.children(":has(> .k-hierarchy-cell .k-minus)"), function(row) {

        console.log(row);
        console.log($(row).data("uid"));
        return grid.dataItem($(row)).EmployeeID; //Use Model Data instead of uid

    });

    grid.one("dataBound", function() {
        grid.expandRow(grid.tbody.children().filter(function(idx, row) {
            return $.inArray(grid.dataItem($(row)).EmployeeID, expanded) >= 0;//Use Model Data instead of uid
        }));
    });

     grid.refresh();


};
```

Thanks to the Telerik support team for this response.   Here is their updated example on [how to persist expanded rows after a refresh](http://dojo.telerik.com/@SiliconSoul/UXaYo) of a Kendo-UI Grid when a dataSource.read() is required.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's because I'm using a different style, or if things have changed from 2015 to 2017, but this didn't work for me as-is.  I had to change ".k-minus" to ".k-i-collapse", for it to work.

The core message is that the overall concept works, but you might have to inspect the classes applied to your rows to find the class names that work for your code.